# Unable to execute unix command using popen

Tags: c, linux, popen, loadrunner, plink

I am trying to run the Unix command from Load Runner using popen. I tried step by step approach below are they

Step 1 :
I first tried logging into the Jump Server

```
fp = popen("plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername", "r");
```

Output using above command in Load runner :
Last login: Thu Jan 11 11:11:11 2018 from some.machine.net

Output manually using Putty :
Using username "abcdef".
Last login: Thu Jan 11 11:11:11 2018 from some.machine.net
abcdef@mymachine:~>

I successfully able to capture the desired result

Step 2 : I want to execute ls command once I am logged into the Jump Server, so I appended the ls command to the above command in the popen

```
fp = popen("plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername ls", "r");
```

then no output is produced and I get an error

In step 1 I am able to capture the output which is "Last login: Thu Jan 11 11:11:11 2018 from some.machine.net"
But in step 2 when I am trying to execute the ls command just by appending in the same popen statement I am getting error.

My objective is to read the output of the ls command

Comment: "I'm getting error": that is rarely useful.

Comment: are you really passing `"plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername some_command"`? because it's trying to execute "some_command", not the name in the variable.

Comment: no that is just for sample...I executed "plink.exe -ssh -l abcd -pw my_password xyz_server ls" command

Comment: ok, but still no detail about the error.

Comment: note that `popen` is deprecated in favour of `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: system(); is the appropriate loadrunner function for shell commands

Comment: Use an RTE virtual user for terminals.

Comment: Getting error as "Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid."

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Getting error as "Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid."

Comment: @Murphy Getting error as "Unable to read from standard input: The handle is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

some_command is  not appended.

```
popen("plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername some_command", "r")
```

should be changed into

```
popen("plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername ${some_command}", "r")
```

Comment: I am trying to execute popen("plink.exe -ssh -l username -pw password Servername ls "r")

Comment: well, is the value of the variable ls equal to "ls"? Or did you mean to assign the string "ls" instead of the variable to some_command?

try this:
some_command = "ls";

Comment: could you show us the error as well? What's happening now is anyones guess.

Comment: I am just getting nothing inside the buffer, count = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, fp); and count is 0